# Can Directory.Build.targets store central version for nuget packages with MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, .net-4.8

Recently learned that Microsoft released a feature with .net Core SDK where developers can have a single source for all the version of nuget packages used in their build solution, Which sounds like a really good idea especially if you have more than 100 projects in your project like us.

The only issue is that our project still works on .NET Framework 4.8 and uses MSBuild (or was it VSBuild) though we have shifted most of our projects to have SDK style `.csproj` file except the ASP.NET projects.

I tried making the central version location for nuget package but couldn't make it work.
Now the question is, Is it even possible to do this for a project that uses MSBuild and still functions on .NET Framework 4.8?

Answer (score 0):

.Net Framework and .Net (Core) both use MSBuild. The dotnet CLI has an embedded version of MSBuild. The `dotnet build` command is using MSBuild.

The .csproj files are MSBuild files. There are two types: 'legacy' and 'sdk'. You noted you have migrated some of the .NET Framework 4.8 projects from 'legacy' to 'sdk'.

Central Package Management (CPM) is a new NuGet feature. From the documentation, CPM works with both 'legacy' and 'sdk' style projects but only works with `PackageReference` and not packages.config.

Are your ASP.NET projects using packages.config?

`PackageReference` support for ASP.NET projects (and C++ projects) is still a work in progress.

To answer the question

> ... is it even possible to do this for a project that uses MSBuild and still functions on .NET Framework 4.8?

Yes, it should be possible to use CPM with a .NET Framework 4.8 project that uses `PackageReference`.

If you have a project that is .NET Framework 4.8, not an ASP.NET project, and using `PackageReference`, does CPM work for that project? Does CPM work for all your projects except the ASP.NET projects (which can't be migrated to `PackageReference`)?

There is definitely a need for hooking into the restore process to add customization. Unfortunately restore behavior and flow is not the same when restoring against a solution versus restoring against a project and there is not a public supported means to hook and get consistent results. This may be an issue if you create a work-around for the ASP.NET projects.

With a project you can have a target that is invoked `BeforeTargets="Restore"`, but that won't be run on a solution level restore. The solution can be extended with a *before.{solution name}.sln.targets* file but these files are not supported by builds within Visual Studio, only by command line builds.